# Getting some negative to positive interval from a positive random number generator?

Tags: algorithms

Imagine I have a random generator. **random(m, n)** returns a random integer between 'm' and 'n' but both $m$ and $n$ needs to be positive integers. Is there any way I could get it to work if I was able to do: **random(-100, 100)**? Perhaps by using multiple randoms or with power rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just subtract half the range as:

$$\mbox{random}(m,n) - \dfrac{m+n}{2}$$

For example, generate a random between $0 \ldots 200$ and subtract $100$.

This will maintain the distribution of your RNG.